# Count properties removing duplicated

Tags: c#

I've an observable collection with a list of `nations`, each nation object have the property `league`. Now each league could be binded more than once, so what I need to do is removing the duplicated property `league` value and count how many leagues are available for each nation. A little practice example:

**DATA STRUCTURE**

```
public class Nation
{
    public string League { get; set; }
}

private static ObservableCollection<Nation> _nations = new ObservableCollection<Nation>();
public ObservableCollection<Nation> Nation
{
   get { return _nations; }
}
```

**DATA POPULATION**

```
Nation nation = new Nation();
nation.League = "ITEM1";
ViewModel.Nation.Add(nation);
nation = new Nation();
nation.League = "ITEM1";
ViewModel.Nation.Add(nation);
```

Now if I bind in xaml the item count:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" />
```

I see `2`, but I need to remove the duplicate and print `1`.

Comment: How do you define `ItemCount` property ? Please edit your question and show that.

Comment: ItemCount is a property of xaml that allow you to get the count of all items binded to the source..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you modify the add method, to make it check for duplicates before you add each item.

```
ViewModel.AddNation(Nation nation);
```

Where the method is something like this:

```
public void AddNation(Nation nation)
{
    if (!_nations.Any(x => x.League == nation.League))
                _nations.Add(nation);

}
```

### Second Way:

You can do the below hack which is not preferred:

```
public ObservableCollection<Nation> Nation
{
    get
    {
        _nations = new ObservableCollection<Nation>(_nations.GroupBy(x => x.League).SelectMany(x => x.Take(1)));
        return _nations;
    }
}
```

Note that I don't recommend the second approach because it changes the state inside the get method.

### Third way:

You can add a new property in your ViewModel that gets Distinct Count and Bind your XAML to this property :

```
public static int NationsItemCount => _nations.Select(x => x.League).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: @Heisenberg I think you might need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or use the first approach and save yourself all that.

Comment: Shouldn't the Binding Source be the ViewModel ? `test` is a Property inside the ViewModel Right ?

Comment: @Heisenberg Do you set `DataContext` as the ViewModel in your XAML ?

Comment: I think you need to bind it this way: `Text="{Binding NationsItemCount, Mode=OneWay}"` because it is a read-only public property.

Comment: It is inside a ListView ? It is not going to work then that way.

Comment: yes, the textblock is inside a listview that bind as source Nation that is an observablecollection. So how can I do to fix it?